# Get the first key for an element in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add an extra class tag if an element / value is the first one found in an array.  The problem is, I don't really know what the key will be...

A minified example of the array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(
            id => 1
            name = Miller
            )
    [1] => Array(
                id => 4
                name = Miller
            )
    [2] => Array(
                id => 2
                name => Smith
    [3] => Array(
                id => 7
                name => Jones
            )
    [4] => Array(
                id => 9
                name => Smith
            )
)
```

So, if it's the first instance of "name", then I want to add a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I sort of understand what you're trying to do. You could loop through the array and check each name. Keep the names you've already created a class for in a separate array.

```
for each element in this array
    if is in array 'done already' then: continue
    else:
        create the new class
        add name to the 'done already' array
```

Sorry for the pseudo-code, but it explains it fairly well.

Edit: here's the code for it...

```
$done = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (in_array($item['name'], $done)) continue;
    // It's the first, do something
    $done[] = $item['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looping through this array. So, a simple condition can be used:

```
$first = 0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!$first++) echo "first class!";
    echo $value;
    // The rest of process.
}
```

To get just the first value of an array, you can also use the old fashioned `reset()` and `current()` functions:

```
reset($arr);
$first = current($arr);
```

Comment: This won't work.  I don't want the first value in an array, I want the first element *per* name in an array.

Comment: well add this name to the condition

Comment: if you want to mark each name's first appearance you have to record previuosly used names, into array.
And check this array against each name.

Answer (score 0):

Animuson has it good. There a small addition if I  might:

```
>  $done = array();  
>  foreach ($array as $item) {
>      if (in_array($item['name'], $done)) continue;
>      // It's the first, do something
>      $done[] = $item['name'];  }
```

the in_array() will get slow very fast. Try something like:

```
$done = array();  
foreach ($array as $item) {
  $key = $item['name'];
  if( !isset( $done[$key] )) {
    ...
  }
  $done[$key] = true;
}
```

btw. Too bad this site doesn't support comments for all users.